# Let plugin add additional JS library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a jQuery plugin which requires another external library (Google Maps in particular).

I would rather not have to add the Google maps script (i.e. `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>`) to my head section, but have the plugin do so.  However, if for what ever reason the page already has the google maps JS on it, I don't want the plugin to duplicate it.

Possible?  If so, how?  Thanks

Comment: Requirejs shim `google.maps` would work. Otherwise `if(!google || !google.maps) $.getScript(script)`

Comment: RequireJS would work. Something I've used in the past (which was super simple to get up and running) was head.js. http://headjs.com/

Comment: @JackPattishallJr.  Thanks.  But then I would need to load head.js, no?

Comment: @megawac.  Same response for requirejs as Jack.  your second solution, however, doesn't have that limitation.